# How to re-initialize a xforms:repeat element in Orbeon, on dropdown select?

Tags: orbeon, xpath-2.0

I have a table that is made with *xforms:repeat* element.

1)When i first run the form,all the fields and calculations are as expected, when in dropdown menu the default item is selected.

The dropdown selection changes the fields of the repeated element (from an xpath expression).

2) When i change the value of the dropdown, it keeps in inputs previous calculated values, they are not updated/recalculated!

3) But weird, if  i reselect Empty Selection and ReSelect a SelectItem, all the calculation work ok!

So, everytime i select EmptyItem and then select an Item, the calculations are working as expected!

I want to re-calculate directly the repeated data, when the value of a dropdown menu changes!

```
...
<xf:repeat ref="instance('fr-form-instance')/Items">
  ...
  <xf:action ev:event="xforms-enabled xxforms-iteration-moved">
  <xf:setvalue ref="(//Item)[xxf:repeat-position()]/TotalCredit" value="someCalculationHere"/>
  <xf:setvalue ref="(//Item)[xxf:repeat-position()]/TotalContingent" value="someCalculationHere"/>
  <xf:recalculate model="fr-form-model"/>
  </xf:action>
    ...
```

In the default option (first option in my case, all are as expected).
[image]

But if i choose something else, it keeps previous values![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement this by listening to events and setting values, but instead, I'd highly recommend you use calculations. Using calculations is more declarative (or some might say "Excel-like"), and it ensures that the calculations are done whenever it is necessary, without you having to make sure you're listening to the appropriate events.

From the look of your form, it seems it might have been created with Form Builder. If that is the case, you can just put the calculations in the *Control Settings* dialog, in the *Formulas* tab, in *Calculated Value*.

Comment: No, i made the form with xf:repeat and a table, for each iteration (row), for each column i set Values with setvalue functions. When the form loads with default Dropdown select, whole table is calculated perfect, but with a different value from the default, only the first calculation is made! I have one bind for each column field.(not nested).

Comment: How to edit the event of dropdown menu, in order to repeat all m elements? How can i setValue to all repeated data inside action from View only?

Comment: So this isn't a form you created with Form Builder? I'm not quite sure to understand why you need to use an `xf:setvalue` and can't use a `calculate` instead, but if need to use a `xf:setvalue` from outside the repeat and have it impact all the iterations in the repeat, you need to have an `iterate="…"` on the `xf:setvalue`, as in https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/3b6e5f51b1ed141602e2e6064f7bf9121131a96a/src/resources/apps/fr/components/universal-submission.xml#L83.

Comment: ok it changes the values!.Can i use position() inside iterate?

Comment: I use this, but it setsValue only to one element!:

<xf:action event="xforms-value-changed">

      <xf:setvalue iterate="instance('form-instance')/Item"
                          ref="(//AnotherItem)[position()]"
                          value="''"/>

</xf:action>

Comment: @oikonomopo This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29526953/5295) answers your follow-up question, correct?