# How to refer to position when using xf:setvalue function with iterate

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms, xpath-2.0

Considering this [code](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/3b6e5f51b1ed141602e2e6064f7bf9121131a96a/src/resources/apps/fr/components/universal-submission.xml#L83) example and [this post](http://blog.orbeon.com/2008/02/more-powerful-xforms-actions-thanks-to_12.html)

```
...
<xf:action>
<xf:setvalue
            iterate="instance('fr-send-submission-params')/@*"
            ref="."
            value="event(name(context()))"/>
</xf:action>
...
```

How can refer to current iterated position? Like `value="position()"`

Can i use this position as variable to xpath expressions? Like `ref="/AnotherElement[position()]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
<xf:action iterate="instance('fr-send-submission-params')/@*">
    <xf:var name="p" value="position()"/>
    <xf:setvalue ref="." value="$p"/>
</xf:action>
```

I don't think you can get away just with `xf:setvalue`, because `ref` changes the evaluation context of the expression to a single item which means that `position()` returns `1` within `value`.

A warning as I see that you iterate on attributes: I don't think that attribute position is guaranteed to be consistent.

**Update:**

The following works if you have elements, but then you need to have knowledge of the items iterated within the `xf:setvalue`:

```
<xf:setvalue
    event="DOMActivate"
    iterate="value"
    ref="."
    value="count(preceding-sibling::value) + 1"/>
```

So I think that the option with an enclosing action is much clearer.